# Does the infinite propagation speed of the heat equation violate special relativity?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I realize that Special Relativity is more of a physics concept than a math one, but I figured that since I learned the heat equation, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \kappa\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} $$ in a PDE math class, I would ask it here.
$$$$
If the heat equation does, in fact, violate SR, is there a relativistic heat equation?

Comment: The top hit on Google for "relativistic heat equation" appears to be the Wikipedia article on [relativistic heat conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_heat_conduction), which gives the equation $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\kappa\left(\nabla^2u-\dfrac1{c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\right)$.

Comment: And if you are not quite ready for the heat equation to become hyperbolic, see [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/268705/53153). There the equation is still parabolic but nonlinear.

Comment: Never mind relativity, it also violates the atomic theory of matter...

Comment: A note regarding the comment of Rahul: $\nabla^2-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$ is in fact the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the Minowski metric.

Comment: @Rahul But that relativistic heat equation is not Lorentz Covariant, is it? Because it contains derivatives of different order: i.e. the time derivative appears once as order 1 and once as order 2. Isn't that annoying? Shouldn't a relativistic heat conduction equation be lorentz covariant?